# Range enumerable with delegate movenext/increase

Tags: .net

I'm trying to print dates starting 2013 1 1 ending 2015 1 1 exclusive.

The problem is MoveNext is called before current so it starts printing at 2013 2 1. My question is 1) Is there some type of Range class that already exist in .NET? I only know of enumerable.range which isn't close to what I need. 2) Is using a `bool hasStarted` and checking it in MoveNext the most idiomatic to fix my problem?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DateTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (var m in Range.Create(new DateTime(2013, 1, 1), new DateTime(2015, 1, 1), s => s.AddMonths(1)))
                Console.WriteLine(m);
        }
    }
    static class Range { public static Range<T> Create<T>(T s, T e, Func<T, T> inc) where T : IComparable<T> { return new Range<T>(s, e, inc); } }
    class Range<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerator<T> where T : IComparable<T> 
    {
        T start, pos, end;
        Func<T,T> inc;
        public Range(T s, T e, Func<T,T> inc) { pos=start= s; end = e; this.inc = inc; }

        public T Current
        {
            get { return pos; }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        object System.Collections.IEnumerator.Current
        {
            get { return pos; }
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            pos = inc(pos);
            return pos.CompareTo(end) < 0;
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            pos = start;
        }

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this;
        }

        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably refactor the code so that I don't have to write `MoveNext()` and `Current` myself:

```
class Range<T> : IEnumerable<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    // other stuff...

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (T val = start; val.CompareTo(end) < 0; val = inc(val))
            yield return val;
    }
}
```

See the [`yield` keyword documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9k7k7cf0.aspx) for more on how this works.

Answer (score 1):

You could use iterators:

```
class Range<T> : IEnumerable<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    T start, pos, end;
    Func<T, T> inc;
    public Range(T s, T e, Func<T, T> inc) { pos = start = s; end = e; this.inc = inc; }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        T current = start;
        while (current.CompareTo(end) < 0)
        {
            yield return current;
            current = inc(current);
        }
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

And you could remove the `Range<T>` class entirely and implement the iterator directly in the static `Range.Create` method.

Comment: Wow this is much cleaner and was something close to what I hoped for.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case when `yield return` can make it unnecessary to create your own custom IEnumerable, as I describe in [this blog post](http://dotnetdom.blogspot.com/2009/04/enumerate-across-date-range-in-linq.html):

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> DaysInRange(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
   DateTime current = startDate;
    while (current <= endDate)
   {
       yield return current;
       current = current.AddDays(1);
   }
}
```

Comment: I definitely need a delegate because I may add by months, weeks or something else. But it looks like other answers may have answered that

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you want (an enumerable list of dates) using the stock `Enumerable.Range()` method, thus:

```
DateTime dtFrom = new DateTime(2013,1,1) ;
DateTime dtThru = new DateTime(2015,1,1) ;
DateTime[] dates = Enumerable.Range( 0 , (dtThru-dtFrom).Days )
                             .Select( x => dtFrom.AddDays(x) )
                             .ToArray()
                             ;
```

Or you could roll your own enumerable `DateRange()` method. Something like this would work. First an enum to specify the size of the interval (There is one available, but you have to suck in the entire VB runtime via the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace to get it. Woof.):

```
public enum DateTimeInterval
{
  Day     = 1 ,
  Week    = 2 ,
  Month   = 3 ,
  Year    = 4 ,
}
```

Then a simple enumerable method:

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> DateRange( DateTime dateFrom , DateTime dateThru , DateTimeInterval interval , int increment )
{
  if ( increment < 1 ) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("increment");

  for( DateTime date = dateFrom.Date ; date <= dateThru ; )
  {

    yield return date ;

    switch (interval )
    {
    case DateTimeInterval.Day   : date = date.AddDays(   increment   ) ; break ;
    case DateTimeInterval.Week  : date = date.AddDays(   increment*7 ) ; break ;
    case DateTimeInterval.Month : date = date.AddMonths( increment   ) ; break ;
    case DateTimeInterval.Year  : date = date.AddYears(  increment   ) ; break ;
    default                     : throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("interval") ;
    }

  }
}
```